# Custom Members Loop with custom order by

Tags: database, buddypress, buddyboss

I have a custom Members Loop in Buddypress including pagination (max. 25 entrys per page) where I want to show some members based on a pre-sorted List of user-ids. These user-ids come from a custom table of mine and are sorted based on one column.

The code looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'bp_after_has_members_parse_args', 'my_custom_users' );
function my_custom_users( $args ) {
    $per_page_setting = 25;
    $page = 1;
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['vpage'] ) ) {
        $page = absint( $_REQUEST['vpage'] );
    }
    
    global $wpdb;
    $user_ids = $wpdb->get_col('SELECT user_id FROM some_table WHERE some_condition = ' . bp_loggedin_user_id() . ' ORDER BY column DESC');
    
    # @see bp_has_members()
    $args['page']     = $page;
    $args['per_page'] = $per_page_setting;
    $args['max']      = count($user_ids);
    $args['include']  = $user_ids;

    return $args;
}
```

Everything works as expected, JUST the sorting is off / wrong, because `bp_has_members()` and `bp_core_get_users()` and `BP_User_Query()` do not maintain it even though it could simply only paginate the list of users I have provided using the "include" parameter.

I tried to do it like this, but that doesnt work because it breaks pagination as Buddypress assumes, this is already the FULL list of user-ids:

```
$args['include']  = array_slice($visitor_ids, ($page-1)*$per_page_setting, $per_page_setting);
```

What would be the appropriate way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `type` parameter?

> 'type' (int) Sort order. Accepts 'active', 'random', 'newest',
> 'popular', 'online', 'alphabetical'. Default: 'active'.

So...  `$args['type']     = 'alphabetical';`
afaik, it will be alphabetical based on first letter of first name.

And do you really need these?

```
$args['page']     = $page;
$args['max']      = count($user_ids);
```

EDIT: To preserve the order, change  `$args['include']` to  `$args['user_ids']`.
BUT `$args['user_ids']` is *not* available in BuddyBoss, only in BuddyPress.

Comment: The "type" parameter doesnt allow me to "keep" / "maintain" my sorting, right? But that's exactly what I was asking for... the ordering comes from my own query beforehand...

Comment: Answer edited above.

Comment: Hi @shanebp, I found I can hook into `bp_pre_user_query_construct`, also in BuddyBoss, and from there set "user_ids". It works like a charm - BUT one caveat it has: It breaks pagination. Do you have any idea how to use pagination (50 entries per page) and still set the user_ids and ordering?

Comment: Confirmed re pagination breaking. I do not have a solution.